# Variável não definida em Class PHP

Tags: php

Criei uma classe PHP para fazer um update nos dados de um registro em uma tabela no banco de dados mysql:

```
<?php

class InsertAccess{

public function insert_access($reg){

    require_once('../conn/conecta.php');

    $status = '1';

    try{
        $sql = "UPDATE `tab_login` SET `last_access` = :date_access, `status` = :sts WHERE `registro` = :reg";
        $access = $conecta->prepare($sql);
        $access->bindParam(":reg", $reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $access->bindParam(":date_access", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $access->bindParam(":sts", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $access->execute();

    }catch (Exception $ex){
        echo 'ERRO: '.$ex;
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Está me dando uma mensagem de variável não definida:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conecta in C:\wamp64\www\my_dir\actions\class_access.php on line 13
```

Alguém pode me dizer qual a forma correta de se usar uma classe php para realizar esse tipo de ação?

**conecta.php**

```
try {       
    $servidor = 'localhost';
    $usuario  = 'root';
    $senha    = '';
    $banco    = 'my_db';

    $conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario , $senha, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $conecta->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERRO DE CONEXÃO: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Chamada da função**

```
$access_class = new InsertAccess();
$access_class->insert_access($item);
```

A classe InsertAccess é um arquivo php separado, sendo que estou utilizando-a em outro arquivo php fazendo a instância como mostrado acima.

Comment: O que tem nesse require no início do método?

Comment: @rray Arquivo que faz a conexão com o banco de dados utilizando PDO.

Comment: Com certeza essa váriavel não está declarada no conecta.php

Comment: **CONECTA**
`$conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario , $senha, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`
`$conecta->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

Comment: @Henqsan Esse código (acima) é todo o conteúdo do aroquivo `conecta.php`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr editei a pergunta e inclui o código todo do conecta.php

Comment: @Henqsan Substitua `echo 'ERRO DE CONEXÃO: ' . $e->getMessage();` por `die('ERRO DE CONEXÃO: ' . $e->getMessage());`, faz mais sentido. Aparece algum erro de conexão ao acessar o método da classe `InsertAccess`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr não há erro de conexão.

Comment: Por que criar uma classe que serve só para executar um insert no banco?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, achei melhor fazer dessa forma, uma vez que posso reutilizar a classe.

Comment: Você poderia fazer apenas uma função sem a classe, conhece o padrão DAO?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, na verdade não sou expert em php, mas vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o padrão DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Problema apresentado na questão foi resolvido utilizando ao invés de `require_once()` o `require()`:

```
class InsertAccess{

public function insert_access($reg){

require('../conn/conecta.php');

$status = '1';
$data_access = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

try{
    $sql = "UPDATE `tab_login` SET `last_access` = :date_access, `status` = :sts WHERE `registro` = :reg";
    $access = $conecta->prepare($sql);
    $access->bindParam(":reg", $reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $access->bindParam(":date_access", $data_access, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $access->bindParam(":sts", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $access->execute();

}catch (Exception $ex){
    echo 'ERRO: '.$ex;
}
} 
}
```

Agradeço a todos pelo ponto negativo na questão e pela extrema e gratificante ajuda.